# PHP DOMXpath not picking anything up

Tags: php, dom, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to write a script that grabs the URL of the first image from this website: http://www.slothradio.com/covers/?adv=&artist=pantera&album=vulgar+display+of+power

Here's my script:

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@class='album0']/img");
echo '<pre>';print_r($elements);exit;
```

When I run that, it outputs

```
DOMNodeList Object
(
)
```

Even when I change my query to `$xpath->query("*/img")`, I still get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/domnodelist use the length property if you want to check for the number of nodes in the node list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$doc->loadHTMLFile($content);` takes in FILE PATH not HTML content see documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Use

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

To Output Element use

```
var_dump(iterator_to_array($elements)); 
//Or
print_r(iterator_to_array($elements));
```

Thanks

:)

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `loadHTML($content)` instead of `loadHTMLFile($content)`, and I'm using `iterator_to_array()`, but I'm still getting nothing. If I use just "*" for the xpath, I get a weird number. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the URL you are pulling but .. have just tested the code on a simple URL and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using `print_r`, but  `DOMNodeList` does not offer any output for that function (because it's an internal class). You can start with outputting the number of items for example. In the end you need to iterate over the node list and deal with each node on your own.

```
printf("Found %d element(s).\n", $elements->length);
```